Which fields actually can be null in the SafeMultisigTransactionResponse model in the Safe Transaction Service API?
As far as I can see, the models from endpoints description don't match the data they return.
For example, this endpoint and address:
https://safe-transaction-polygon.safe.global/api/v1/safes/0xFcf23C3B0b3Ef21381A3a88B7244168D03e15Ae1/multisig-transactions/
The transaction with safeTxHash = "0x50995b0a26ab61284bffac268b7052b416e4f88c61423733bdeba9a62154e387", the transactionHash and executionDate columns are null but in the SafeMultisigTransactionResponse model in the description they are marked as non-nullable.
Is it a problem in the data or in the description?

The problem comes from Swagger description. The example provided is for successful transactions, but the data structure can vary if it did not go through. We are currently working on a new documentation for our API services, which should make it much clearer.
Thanks for pointing it out though. Best, Louis
